# Which python ORM could return an object?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm learning sqlalchemy now ,with raw sql execute like this:

```
class Qblvpool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "hhe"
        self.size = 0
        self.createtime = datetime.now()


metadata = MetaData()
qblvpool = Table('qb_lv_pool', metadata,
                 Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                 Column('name', String(128)),
                 Column('size', Integer),
                 Column('createtime', DateTime))

mapper(Qblvpool, qblvpool)

engine =     create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@ip:5432/postgres', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
result = session.execute('select * from qb_lv_pool', mapper=Qblvpool)
row = result.fetchone()
print row.name
```

It's worked fine.But I want the row to be an instance of Qblvpool,just like ibatis did in java.

How can I  did this or which python ORM support it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is described in the docs under [Using Textual SQL](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql):

```
session.query(Qblvpool).from_statement(text('select * from qb_lv_pool')).all()
```

Comment: great !that is what I need! Thanks!

Comment: @user3323381 Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use session.query instead of session.execute

```
session.query(Qblvpool).all()
```

Comment: ... and so that allow you to do it without an ORM.

Comment: No....he like the connection pool.....I will try univerio's answer first and thanks for your reply so much!